# I'm embedding jetty in my app to communicate over websockets, how can define different paths?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a java server which needs to communicate with web clients in real-time. In order to do this, I'm embedding Jetty 9. Jetty will serve as a static web server to web clients, as well as a websocket server. Based on the examples I've found online, the static page handler and the WS handler are both served off the same path. I'm not clear how to get jetty to serve them from two different paths. I'll appreciate any pointers. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String ...args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });
    resource_handler.setResourceBase("./webapp");


    WebSocketHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
            factory.register(MyWebSocketHandler.class);
        }
    };

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler,wsHandler, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ContextHandlerCollection` and wrap your `WebSockets` in `ContextHandler` objects.

```java
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.addHandler(new ContextHandler(wsFooHandler, "/foo"));
    contexts.addHandler(new ContextHandler(wsBarHandler, "/bar"));

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, contexts, new DefaultHandler() });
```

However, using the `ServletContextHandler` with the `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` and its `addMapping` allows you to control things with websocket creation in a much more powerful way.

Example:

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
{
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });

    WebSocketUpgradeFilter filter = WebSocketUpgradeFilter.configureContext(context);

    filter.addMapping(new ServletPathSpec("/foo/*"),new SingleWebSocketCreator(FooSocket.class));
    filter.addMapping(new ServletPathSpec("/bar/*"),new SingleWebSocketCreator(BarSocket.class));
    filter.addMapping(new ServletPathSpec("/*.ws"),new SingleWebSocketCreator(WsTypeSocket.class));
    filter.addMapping(new RegexPathSpec("/chat/room/[a-zA-z_]*/public"),new SingleWebSocketCreator(ChatSocket.class));

    // add your own non-websocket servlets
    context.addServlet(HelloServlet.class,"/hello");

    // Lastly, the default servlet for root content (serves up static content)
    // It is important that this is last.
    ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
    holderPwd.setInitParameter("resourceBase","./webapp");
    holderPwd.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
    context.addServlet(holderPwd,"/");

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { context, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

And the accidentally left out SingleWebSocketCreator ...

```java
public class SingleWebSocketCreator implements WebSocketCreator
{
    private Class<?> endpoint;

    public SingleWebSocketCreator(Class<?> websocketEndpoint)
    {
        this.endpoint = websocketEndpoint;
    }

    @Override
    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req, ServletUpgradeResponse resp)
    {
        try
        {
            // new instance of endpoint for each upgrade
            return endpoint.newInstance();
        }
        catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            // failure to instantiate can flow out
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response! I didn't quite get `SingleWebSocketCreator` is that supposed to be a built-in class?

Comment: Whoops, added it to answer, its just a super simple implementation of WebSocketCreator